# Write several Hashmaps into new csv file

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

For a HW I need to:
- Read a couple of CSV files into Hashmaps (already completed that)
- Write specific keys of these Hashmaps into a new CSV file in the main method.

The final csv file has the keys "customerno" , "lastname" , "firstname", "invoiceno", "totalamount".

The first three keys (customerno, lastname, firstname) are in a Hashmap called "customers".

The key "invoiceno" is in a Hashmap called "invoiceitem".

The key "totalamount" is a product of the keys "productno" & "quantity" and the matching "price" key from the csv file called "product" (this also needs to be matched to the "invoiceno".

The output csv file also needs to be sorted.

My current main method looks like this:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    InvoiceSystem invoiceSystem = new InvoiceSystem();
    invoiceSystem.readCustomers();
    invoiceSystem.readInvoices();
    invoiceSystem.readProductGroups();
    invoiceSystem.readProducts();
    invoiceSystem.readInvoiceItems();

    System.out.printf("Customers     : %5d ( == %5d)\n", invoiceSystem.getCustomers().size(), 210);
    System.out.printf("Invoices      : %5d ( == %5d)\n", invoiceSystem.getInvoices().size(), 300);
    System.out.printf("ProductGroups : %5d ( == %5d)\n", invoiceSystem.getProductGroups().size(), 5);
    System.out.printf("Products      : %5d ( == %5d)\n", invoiceSystem.getProducts().size(), 27);
    System.out.printf("InvoiceItems  : %5d ( == %5d)\n", invoiceSystem.getInvoiceItems().size(), 2019);

    String headline = "customerno"+";"+"lastname"+";"+"firstname"+";"+"invoiceno"+";"+"totalamount";     

    Map<Integer,Customer> outputCus = new HashMap<>(invoiceSystem.getCustomers());


    try {


    File file = new File("c:\\output.csv");

    if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.append(headline);
    bw.newLine();

            for(Map.Entry<Integer,Customer> abc : outputCus.entrySet()){

                bw.write(abc.getKey().toString());
                bw.write(";");
                bw.write(abc.getValue().toString());
                bw.write("\r\n"); 
            }

            bw.close();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


}
}
```

This is the current .csv output that I get --> [current csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwlXKECpA-rfcUVSQ0NXeEoyOGM)

Any advice on how to go forward? I'm running against walls right now. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update the whole code and input csv files.

Comment: Also please use a comma (,) in-place of semicolon (;) so that files can be open in google sheet.